# How to get rid of Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

I am new to Linux and C. Currently I am trying to create the game "Robots" and now I am getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int x; //row
int y; //column
int robots;
int walls;
char playfield[0][0];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf("Enter the size of the Y-Axis! It should be bigger that 5 and lower that 75!\n");
    printf("It is recommended that you use uneven numbers!\n");
    scanf("%i", &x);
    if(x > 75 || x < 5) {
        printf("Learn to read!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Enter the size of the Y-Axis! It should be bigger that 5 and lower that 75!\n");
    printf("It is recommended that you use uneven numbers!\n");
    scanf("%i", &y);
    if(y > 75 || y < 5) {
        printf("Learn to read!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Enter the amount of walls!\n");
    scanf("%i", &walls);
    printf("Now enter the amount of robots!\n");
    scanf("%i", &robots);

    playfield[x][y], "\0";

    //Sets the value of every char in the [][] to '-'
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            playfield[i][j] = '-';
        }
    }

    playfield[x/2][y/2] = 'O'; //Gets the spawnpoint of the player
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            printf("%c ", playfield[i][j], "\0");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    placeObjects(walls, '#');

    return 0;
}

//Spawns walls and robots
void placeObjects(int amountOfObjs, char Obj) {
    int ObjX = rand() % (x + 1);
    int ObjY = rand() % (y + 1);
    for(int i = 0; i <= amountOfObjs; i++) {
        int ObjX = rand() % (x + 1);
        int ObjY = rand() % (y + 1);
        if(playfield[ObjX][ObjY] == '-') { 
            playfield[ObjX][ObjY] = Obj;
        } else {
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `char playfield[0][0];` <<-- that is a very small playfield!

Comment: How does `char playfield[0][0];` even compile? Isn't there a warning? And what is the line `playfield[x][y], "\0";` supposed to do?

Comment: There are two other warnings: `printf("%c ", playfield[i][j], "\0");` arguments don't match the specifiers, and function `placeObjects()` lacks a declaration. You really must enable and act on compiler warnings.

Comment: Why not use `make CFLAGS="-Wall -g" your_program` to buld your program, and then use `gdb your_program` to run it. If there is an error use gdb's `bt` (backtrace) to see where the problem was. You can switch to the right frame using `frame #` (where # is the number) and inspect the local variables using `info locals`.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `gcc -c -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 yoursource name.c -o yoursourcename.o`  Then when you have all the warnings corrected, then use `gcc -ggdb yoursourcename.o -o yoursourcename`

Comment: your function signatures need to be declared before they are used.  so either list all (except main()) signatures before the first actual function or move the `main()` function to after everything else.

Comment: when calling `rand()`,  always call `srand()` first to 'prime the pump'  Suggest, at beginning of main() to insert: `srand( (unsigned)time( NULL) );`  of course that means the header file: `time.h` needs to be included.

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`  since neither `argc` nor `argv[]` are used, it would eliminate two warnings about unused parameters to use the other valid `main()` signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: when retrieving `robots` and `walls` the code should be verifying that the values are > 0 and < some max value

Comment: the `scanf)` family of functions return the number of successful 'input format conversion specifiers' (or EOF).  The code should be checking those returned values

Comment: regarding: `playfield[x][y], "\0";`  the valid index into an array has the range of 0...(number of elements -1) so this statement can modify the memory immediately after the end of the array, which results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: regarding: `printf("%c ", playfield[i][j], "\0");`  1) this is not a valid statement, is has 1 too many parameters.  2) the format string is trying to output 2 characters, BUT the `playfield` entries are only one byte each,  That second character is beyond the end of the entry in `playfield` resulting in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: regarding: `int ObjX = rand() % (x + 1);
    int ObjY = rand() % (y + 1);`  these statements can return 0.  And why perform the calculations twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared statically 1x1 matrix - and you try to set the values above 1x1.
Hence change the 6th line to:

```
char playfield[70][70]
```

you have some additional warnings - try to get rid of them as well.
Meantime this is what I got:

[image]

Comment: `char playfield[70][70] ` may not be enough because `x` and `y` can be at most 75.

Comment: Also [please do not post images of texts because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Texts should be posted directly **as text** in your posts.

Comment: indeed @MikeCAT - it should be:  char playfield[76][76]

Answer (score 0):

The array `playfield` is declared to have zero elements, to it is not allowed to access any elements of that.

Since the maximum allowed values for `x` and `y` are limited, you can allocate enough elements of the array statically.

```
char playfield[76][76];
```

(The maximum allowed values for `x` and `y` are 75, and `ObjX` and `ObjY` will be at most `x` and `y` respectively, so you will need at least 76 elements)

Another way is allocating some elements dynamically according to the `x` and `y` entered.

It can be done like this:

```c
char** playfield;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    /* ... */

    /* allocate buffer for y * x elements */
    char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(*buffer) * y * x);
    if (buffer == NULL) return 1;
    /* allocate buffer for x pointers for each row */
    playfield = malloc(sizeof(*playfield) * x);
    if (playfield == NULL) return 1;
    /* assign pointers to each row */
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        playfield[i] = buffer + y * i;
    }

    /* ... */

    /* de-allocate what are allocated (for satisfying checkers like Valgrind) and exit */
    free(buffer);
    free(playfield);
    return 0;
}
```